# Transfer loan to other wallet

Tags: transactions, ether, erc-20, defi

Say I have deposited to the y-pool at [curve.fi](https://curve.fi) and staked the corresponding crv tokens at the gauge. Is it possible to transfer that "loan" to another wallet without unstaking?